# Getting error when trying to launch node.js app with PM2 Cluster

Tags: node.js, pm2

in an Ubuntu Server, I am unable to run the node.js app in cluster mode using PM2.

The command I use is :

> PM2 start server.js --name Server -i max

When I list the PM2 processes, I can see the *Server* has Error status.
I have tried looking into  the log file generated by PM2 but it's empty.

I am however able to run the same server.js without the cluster mode using :

> PM2 start server.js --name Server

Answer (score 23, accepted):

doing `PM2 Kill` and starting all the services again was the solution to above issue.

Answer (score 7):

You could also have used `pm2 restart Server` to restart it

If you use `pm2 kill` you will just kill all processes, to clean up afterwards i would recommend to use `pm2 flush` so all logfiles will be reset

Comment: pm2 restart server didn't work in my situation. I used it several times before doing pm2 kill

Answer (score 4):

I have gone through this same kind of situations but in my case pm2 is showing error status cause of error in my code.
use the below command

```
pm2 logs
```

pm2 logs command helped me by showing some hints to check where exactly the error is occured.

if everything works fine then `pm2 list` will show you the status online.

you can check the ports running by pm2(not only pm2 but all the process) using below command

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```